# Magento product export to MySQL

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a Magento EC2 instance on AWS (1.9.2.2-1 on Ubuntu 14.04.1), I am trying to export the products through the admin panel, System-Import/Export-Dataflow profiles- Export All Products, The data transfer method is set Local/Remote Server, the type is Local Server, Path is var/export. Then I go to Run Profile and click on Run Profile in Popup, the execution starts and everything has a green tick mark with the last row saying Saved successfully:"export_all_products.csv", then Finished profile execution. But when I go and enter the EC2 instance either through FileZilla or just SSH into it and look into the path for the file, there is no file. Could anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?